# use picture from pc instead of camera image in emulator

Tags: android

In my application i have to use camera to take picture and analize, but i dont have a webcam with my PC.

In this application after taking a snap it automatically start analizing

Is it possible to use any picture stored in my pc to treat it as taken from camera for continuing the further process ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load this picture to the sd card of the emulator and then access it, analyze it, etc. You can't access directly from your pc.